# How to setup people viewer

Tags: google-app-maker

[appmaker] I am trying to setup people viewer and it doesn't load any job title, location, or manager data. How can I go about getting this data inputted for each employee?

Comment: please share your efforts !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data cannot come from outer space, you need to put it in first. [People Viewer template](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/people-viewer/) relies on Directory Model that reads data from [Admin Directory](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1628009). So, you need to navigate there and add information you need.

Comment: Wow, I contacted google support and they told me that there is no area for users titles but look there it is.

Where does the location data pull from? it doesn't appear to pull from the user work location in basic information.

Comment: I'm not Directory expert and I don't have access to it, but afaik `PrimaryOrganizationLocation` should be extracted from the primary organization associated with the user(there should be a way, to associate user with organization(s)). Maybe this reference will be helpful: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users